# If I chop my apple into smaller pieces, can I fit more apple in my lunchbox?

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

Well, that's how my little sister asked it, and I couldn't provide a quick answer.

If we ignore any changes in *shape* from the cutting process, then my first thought was that the scaling wouldn't make any difference. But then I started thinking that more efficient packings might only become possible after we cut the apple pieces down to a certain size.

I realise this is almost unanswerable without multiple assumptions (spherical pieces of apple anyone? :) ) but at the end of the day I'm interested in what is known (if anything) about the packing of irregularly shaped solids in finite containers of similar dimension (within an order of magnitude) to the solids themselves.

Thanks

Comment: Let $a$ be the diameter of an apple. Look at lunchboxes of height $<a$, but large other dimensions. Then you can fit $0$ apples in the box, but many if you make apple sauce. If details are provided about dimensions, more specific numerical bounds can be given.

Comment: Well obviously you can. Consider the limit: if you grind your apples to a paste, you can use up the entire volume of the lunch box, while with full apples you're very unlikely to. Look up [packing problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) -- you can also click on the tag below your question. :-)

Comment: surely if the shape of the apple remains the same (so we're not just going to a paste, they remain, say, spheres) then the limit as their size goes to 0 doesn't correspond to filling 100% of the volume of the container?

Comment: @AndréNicolas if numerical bounds could indeed be established, would it make any difference for, say, a 10cm * 10cm * 10cm container whether the irregular shapes where ~3cm in size or ~1cm in size. I guess that's the gist of the question.

Comment: @tom: Yes, it would make a difference. It is clear that it makes a difference if the change in size is large enough (keeping shape unchanged). For your numerical example, assuming exactness, it also makes a difference.

Comment: @tom - when you cut an apple with a knife, the pieces you get are more like cubes than like spheres.  So how about the following:  Get the lunch box (or a handy rectangular container) and fill it with marbles, or apples.  Pour water into the remaining space.  Remove the marbles and measure the water.  Now do the same with blocks -- pack with blocks, fill the remainder with water, remove blocks, measure amount of water.  (These kinds of experiments lead to interesting places!)

Comment: I shall suggest this to my sister :)

Comment: Why do you think that smaller identical spheres fill space better? The same fraction is still gaps!! Look up sphere packing... You will **never** get more than 75% filled.

Answer (score 0):

This restates some of the discussion in the comments, but here is a more rigorous proof of what I take this question to be asking:

Say that a 3D shape is "reasonable" if it has positive volume and the limit as $\epsilon\to0^+$ of the volume of the points within distance $\epsilon$ of its boundary is $0$.

In apple terms, we're requiring the apple is not all peel - if you take a fine enough apple-peeler, you can remove the peel without taking out any significant part of the apple. (This is to avoid pathological shapes that are arbitrarily close to their boundary and otherwise hard to dice up nicely.)

**Claim:** Given a reasonably-shaped apple and a reasonably-shaped lunchbox with more volume than the apple, it is possible to cut the apple into finitely many pieces with a knife so that they can be rearranged to fit inside the lunchbox.

**Proof:** Suppose that the ratio $\frac{\text{Volume}(\text{box})}{\text{Volume}(\text{apple})}$ is equal to some $r>1$.

Let $\epsilon_1>0$, and cut the apple along planes normal to the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes so that it is cut along a grid of cubes of side length $\epsilon_1$. Extend every nonempty piece until it fills up its corresponding cube. By our reasonableness property, this will give us a set of cubes with total volume approaching $\text{Vol}(\text{apple})$ from above as $\epsilon_1\to0$. (This is because any cube which contains some of the apple has no points more than $\epsilon_1\sqrt{3}$ outside the boundary.)

Conversely, if we cut the *box* along planes normal to the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes so that it is cut along a grid of cubes of side length $\epsilon_2>0$, our reasonableness property tells us that the cubes which fit entirely inside the box (without touching the boundary) will have total volume approaching $\text{Vol}(\text{box})$ from below as $\epsilon_2\to0$.

So then we can choose $\epsilon$ small enough that cutting the box into cubes of side length $\epsilon$ gives us "inside cubes" with total volume at least $\frac{\text{Vol}(\text{box})}{\sqrt{r}}$, and cutting the apple into cubes of side length $\epsilon$ gives us "outside cubes" with total volume at most $\text{Vol}(\text{apple})\cdot\sqrt{r}$.

But then we have at least as many empty lunchbox cubes to fill as we have partially-filled apple cubes to place inside, so we can just pair up the (identically-shaped) cubes with each other however we like. This completes the proof. (In fact, for most nice apple and lunchbox shapes it will do so in a relatively small number of knife cuts, because we only need to make $O(1/\epsilon)$ cuts in order to produce $O(1/\epsilon^3)$ pieces.)

---

If you place any absolute bound on the number of pieces, then it is not necessarily possible to do this, even for apples and lunchboxes of similar dimensions. Consider a worm-eaten apple with many tiny holes inside it, so that it is more like a collection of soap bubble films - even though its volume is very small, it takes a large number of cuts to allow these holes to be filled nicely and to pack it into a tighter space.